# Python issue when reading from a file

Tags: python, file

Hello so i was doing a school project and I wrote this out I got it all working so my next task was to make it to read the message from an file so i changed the definition where it asked for the message which is UserMessage() so i run the code it works it prints out whats in the text file but when i do the last bit where it gets the final answer it shows this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\christian\Desktop\Python\2 keywor with cypher code.py", line 138, in <module>
    Restart()
  File "C:\Users\christian\Desktop\Python\2 keywor with cypher code.py", line 127, in Restart
    Text = TranslateMessage2(Key2, Message2, Option)
  File "C:\Users\christian\Desktop\Python\2 keywor with cypher code.py", line 107, in TranslateMessage2
    Translated.append(symbol)    # The symbol was not in LETTERS, so add it to translated as is.
NameError: name 'Translated' is not defined






import pyperclip

Valid_Letters = 'ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY' # This is where it stores the Letters witch are being used in the program

def Linespacer():
    print('================================================================')

def GetOption(): # This is the first queston in the program witch is asking if they want to encrypt decrypt
    while True:
        print('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?')
        Option = input().lower()
        if Option in 'encrypt e decrypt d'.split():
            return Option  # This is where if the user does not enter the right ifomation it goes back tot he top and ask the question
        else:
            print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".') # If the user doers not enter the right thing for example if they enter an 'l' it prints that message


def UserMessage():
    mes = str(input('would you like to encrypt or decrypt from a file or type your own message?(file/f or message/m): '))
    if mes == 'f' or mes == 'file':
        name = str(input("What is the document you want to read called?: "))
        with open(name, "rt") as in_file:
            text = in_file.read()
        print(text)
        return text
    if mes == 'm' or mes == 'message':
        text = str(input('Enter your message: '))            


def UserKeyword(): # This def is what ask the user for the Message and gathers the infomation
    print('Enter your First keyword:') # Prints out the message asking for the keyword
    return input()

def UserKeyword2(): # This def is what ask the user for the Message and gathers the infomation
    print('Enter your Second keyword:') # Prints out the message asking for the keyword
    return input()

def TranslateMessage(Key, Message, Option): # This is the main def and where it does all of the maths when you call the def it reqires 3 Variables 
    Translated = [] # stores the encrypted/decrypted message string
    keyIndex = 0 # This is the defult keyIndex when the program is started
    Key = Key.upper() # This is allowing the user to have Upper case letters or lowercase letters

    for symbol in Message: # loop through each character in message

        num = Valid_Letters.find(symbol.upper()) #

        if num != -1: # -1 means symbol.upper() was not found in LETTERS

            if Option == 'encrypt' or Option == 'e':
                num += Valid_Letters.find(Key[keyIndex]) #This makes it so if they are encrypting it adds

            elif Option == 'decrypt' or Option == 'd':

                num -= Valid_Letters.find(Key[keyIndex]) # This makes it so if they are decrypting it subtract

            num %= len(Valid_Letters) 

            if symbol.isupper():
                Translated.append(Valid_Letters[num])

            elif symbol.islower():

                Translated.append(Valid_Letters[num].lower())
            keyIndex += 1 # move to the next letter in the key
            if keyIndex == len(Key):
                keyIndex = 0
        else:

            Translated.append(symbol)    # The symbol was not in LETTERS, so add it to translated as is.


    return ''.join(Translated) # It joins all of the functions together so the user can have all of the text together

def TranslateMessage2(Key2, Message2, Option): # This is the main def and where it does all of the maths when you call the def it reqires 3 Variables 
    Translated2 = [] # stores the encrypted/decrypted message string
    keyIndex = 0 # This is the defult keyIndex when the program is started
    Key2 = Key2.upper() # This is allowing the user to have Upper case letters or lowercase letters


    for symbol in Message2: # loop through each character in message

        num = Valid_Letters.find(symbol.upper()) #

        if num != -1: # -1 means symbol.upper() was not found in LETTERS

            if Option == 'encrypt' or Option == 'e':

                num += Valid_Letters.find(Key2[keyIndex]) #This makes it so if they are encrypting it adds

            elif Option == 'decrypt' or Option == 'd':

                num -= Valid_Letters.find(Key2[keyIndex]) # This makes it so if they are decrypting it subtract

            num %= len(Valid_Letters) 

            if symbol.isupper():
                Translated2.append(Valid_Letters[num])

            elif symbol.islower():

                Translated2.append(Valid_Letters[num].lower())
            keyIndex += 1 # move to the next letter in the key
            if keyIndex == len(Key2):
                keyIndex = 0
        else:

            Translated.append(symbol)    # The symbol was not in LETTERS, so add it to translated as is.


    return ''.join(Translated2) # It joins all of the functions together so the user can have all of the text together

def PlayAgainMessage():
    again = str(input("Would you like to restart Y or N: "));
    Linespacer()
    if again == "Y" or again == "y": # This is an if statment it is saying that if the user types "Y" it runs the code to restart the program
        Restart();                           # If the user types "N" it Exits the program
    elif again == "N" or again == "n":
        exit()


def Restart(): # This is the def which allows the user to restart the prgram once they have done it
    Option = GetOption()
    Message = UserMessage()
    Key = UserKeyword()
    Key2 = UserKeyword2()
    Message2 = TranslateMessage(Key, Message, Option)
    Text = TranslateMessage2(Key2, Message2, Option)
    Linespacer()
    print('Your translated text is: %s' % Text) # Prints the message and get the text which has been encrypt or decrypt
    pyperclip.copy(Text) 
    Linespacer()
    name = str(input("What would you like to name the File: "))
    name1 = str; 
    file = open(name+".txt", "w")
    file.write(Text)
    file.close()    
    PlayAgainMessage()
Restart()
```

Comment: Your second message translate function uses Translate2 not Translate. :) small typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You left a *Translated* in your TranslateMessage2 when you probably meant to change it to *Translated2*.

In TranslateMessage2:

```
Translated.append(symbol)
```

Should be:

```
Translated2.append(symbol)
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `Translated` in `TranslateMessage` but not in `TranslateMessage2`

As a result `Translated` does not exist within the global namespace, nor the namespace of `TranslateMessage2`.

Assuming you intentionally wanted to append to `Translated` and not `Translated2` you either need to make `Translated`  `global` variable or assign it to a variable through your `TranslateMessage` function.

To make `Translated` global you simply need to initialise it outside of the function.